# Не открывается страница через Live Server плагин для VS Code в браузере

Tags: visual-studio, плагин

Всем привет!

Заранее хочу сказать что *я нашёл решения проблемы и хотел поделиться этим с вами!* После установки **VS Code** хотел как можно быстрее начать работать в нём(так уж очееень приятно).

Устанавливал дополнительные плагины для него, один из них очень удобный - **Live Server**, вот только проблема, с пачки он не хотел открывать проект в браузере, только если вручную набрать ip/port(*127.0.0.1:5500/index.html*), то работал.

Вот для того чтобы он в вас запускался автоматически нужно прописать в **Системных Переменных** вот такую строчку --->>> ***C:\Windows\System32***, *вот и магия заработала, поздравляю*!!!

Надеюсь кому то это будёт полезно *;)*

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста как прописать в Системных Переменных эту строчку? Не могу найти, это в VS Code?

Comment: правой кнопкой кликаешь на мой ПК и настройки, там есть слева панель, и кликаешь на последний пункт, далее переменные и добавляешь новую)

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но результата нет. У меня браузер Яндекс , может в этом проблема?

Comment: попробуйте в Chrome, если не поможет то проблема в самом VS Code

Comment: Во всех браузерах пробовал, результата нет. VS скачивал с официального сайта, переустанавливал. Может браузер по умолчанию должен быть хром? Замучила эта проблема(

Comment: Именно все так как я описал выше или нет?может путь к vs не прописан в системе

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решила эту проблему так: как советует автор поста открыла свойства компьютера -- дополнительные параметры системы -- переменные среды -- а дальше самодеятельность: открыла переменную среду для пользователя (верхняя) -- нашла PATH -- вместо того, что там было вставила `C:\Windows\System32` и магия свершилась

Comment: Круто, что помогло!